# Modifying EF result and serialize to client

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm fetching a list of keys from the database, which I modify based on certain conditions. The list gets serialized as a response to an AJAX call.

But when I modify the list several times along the way, Resharper tells me "`possible multiple enumeration of ienumerable`".

Should I just use `ToList()` on all my lines where the list is involved?

Please recommend a suitable approach:

```
IEnumerable<decimal> foo = databaseContext.Foo.Select(f=>f.Key);

if(something)
    foo = foo.Where(f=>f.Bar > 5);

if(somethingElse)
    foo = foo.Where(f=>f.Bar > 15);

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(new { fooKeys = foo.ToList() });

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper is right in its analysis. You potentially have multiple execution of your query. The problem is in your very first line:

```
IEnumerable<decimal> foo = databaseContext.Foo.Select(f=>f.Key);
```

In Entity Framework, few extensions will materialize a query. One of them is `AsEnumerable()`.  The right part of your line effectively construct an `IQueryable` but the left hand part is an `IEnumerable`. At that point, the `IQueryable` will be implicitly casted to an `IQueryable` by calling `AsEnumerable` and you query will be materialized.

If you want to defer the execution of a query, the left-hand side should be `IQueryable` (use `var` for simplicity):

```
var foo = databaseContext.Foo.Select(f=>f.Key);
```

Also, I'm guessing this is an oversight on you part, but `foo` is an enumerable of `decimal` and yet, you filter the `Bar` property. This wouldn't even compile.

**Edit:** I've took the liberty to modify your original code (the first part) to show you a breakdown:

```
// databaseContext.Foo is a (presumably) DbSet<Foo> that implements 
// IQueryable<Foo>. Because the variable foo is set to be an IEnumerable<Foo> 
// and that IQueryable<Foo> implements IEnumerable<Foo> by calling 
// as AsEnumerable(), any further manipulation of the IEnumerable<Foo>
// will be with LINQ to Object and not Linq to SQL (with Entity Framework)
IEnumerable<Foo> foo = databaseContext.Foo;

// Because of the previous point, this will potentially execute the query
if(something)
    foo = foo.Where(f=>f.Bar > 5);

// And this will as well
if(somethingElse)
    foo = foo.Where(f=>f.Bar > 15);

// And ToList() will definitely execute it.
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(new { fooKeys = foo.Select(f => f.Key).ToList() });

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
```

Now, if you do this instead:

```
// DbSet<Foo> will create an IQueryable<Foo>. An Entity Framework IQueryProvider
// will compile this to an SQL when we want to materialize the query
IQueryable<Foo> foo = databaseContext.Foo;

// Now, if this is hit, it's fine because IQueryable.Where returns an IQueryable
// of the same type. We still live in the 
if(something)
    foo = foo.Where(f=>f.Bar > 5);

// Same point as before. foo is still an IQueryable<Foo> and the materialization
// is not provoked yet.
if(somethingElse)
    foo = foo.Where(f=>f.Bar > 15);

// Here, foo.Select() will return an IQueryable<decimal> (or whatever the type
// of the Foo.Key property is) and then ToList() will get the IEnumerable<decimal>
// version. At that point, any further manipulation is done through Linq to Object
// but the query won't be sent to the database until it is iterated (ie
// the IEnumerable<decimal>.GetEnumerator() is called). The IEnumerable<decimal>
// version of the will be passed to the List<T>(IEnumerable<T>) constructor
// which will iterate through the Enumerable with the GetEnumerator method.
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(new { fooKeys = foo.Select(f => f.Key).ToList() });

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
```

As you can see, by using `IQueryable` in the begining and up until the `ToList()`, you will still live in the `IQueryable` deferred query execution world and Resharper will stop complaining.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is it a bad idea to make it a generic list from the start and use `Where().Tolist()` in each if case?

Comment: Yes. ToList() will execute a query. The first one will execute from the database, then the rest will all create intermediate lists. You should consider holding to your IQueryable for as long as you can and deffer the execution to when your query to the database is good.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I make a `IQueriable<decimal>` instead of `IEnumerable<decimal>` at the top -> modify it in the same way as I do today -> run `ToList()` at the end? Wouldn't this cause the same issue as resharper is warning me about now?

Comment: @Johan An IQueryable does not enumerate at any point. An IEnumerable will.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. If I use `IEnumerable` like in my example, the problem remains. Could you show an example on your suggested approach?

Comment: @Johan I'm on my phone, I'll edit my answer with more detail in an hour

Comment: Thanks for elaborating Simon

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not correct when you do a select on an objectset you get a queryable I think you can not assign the queryable to IEnumerable.

A queryAble doesn't actually do a request against the db until you use the IQueryable<>  ToList() method.

So you first should define your query, and then execute it against the db with the ToList() method which will return a List of your Type.

You should rearrange your code to something like this.

```
var resultSetInMemory = new List<decimal>();

if(somethink) {
 resultSetInMemory = databaseContext.Foo
                                    .Where(f=>f.Bar > 5)
                                    .Select(f.key)
                                    .ToList();
}

if(somethingElse) {
 resultSetInMemory = databaseContext.Foo
                                   .Where(f=>f.Bar > 15)
                                   .Select(f.key)
                                   .ToList();
}

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(new { fooKeys = resultSetInMemory });
```

This is the approach I have seen a lot. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: So you're suggesting to potentially have two query executed against the database while losing the result of the first one and not even get the same result as he should?

Comment: Ah, no that would not be so good. You are right. The better way is to say ToList() at the end of the function where you would typicaly return your result.